# What's the best database structure for a Rails app like Wufoo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, data-structures

I am not intending to rebuild Wufoo on Rails but want to create an app along those lines.

Any advice on the best app/database structure for this?

Comment: What do you have so far?  Let's see if we can't refine this idea further.

Comment: @crftr, I essentially want to create an app that allows creating of forms fields on-the-fly—essentially a "dynamic" model that doesn't require coding to add new fields. I imagine it would store the field names/types/default values/etc in serialised hashes, right? Of course, this might make it difficult to efficiently index/search. Any ideas on optimal data structure for something like this? Is there a gem already available for this?

Answer (score 0):

A postgres hstore strategy would be preferable to serializing.  And yes, [there's a gem for activerecord hstore support](https://github.com/engageis/activerecord-postgres-hstore).

To quote their readme:

> You need dynamic columns in your tables. What do you do?
>
> - Create lots of tables to handle it. Nice, now you’ll need more models
>     and lots of additional sqls. Insertion and selection will be slow as
>     hell.
> - Use a noSQL database just for this issue. Good luck.
> - Create a serialized column. Nice, insertion will be fine, and reading data from
>     a record too. But, what if you have a condition in your select that
>     includes serialized data? Yeah, regular expressions.